# How to autoload PHP 5.3 classes?

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I am trying to autoload my PHP 5.3 namespaced classes eg.

```
/JM
    Auth.php
    User.php
    Db/Entity.php
    / ...
```

I did

```
namespace KM;

class Autoloader {
    public static function registerAutolaod() {
        ini_set('include_path', dirname(__FILE__) . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));
        spl_autoload_register(function ($classname) {
            $file = preg_replace('/\\\/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $classname) . '.php';
            echo $file . '<br />';
            include ($file);

        });
    }
}
```

Problem is sometimes I get classname as `User` sometimes `KM\User` how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$classname` you receive in your callback function will be assumed to be local. That's because you have defined your __autoloader within a namespace.

To always get the absolute / fully qualified namespace and class name, declare your autoloader in the global scope. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php#87985